# Remove all spaces and non-first letters from words in a string

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

I'm stuck at a PHP/RegEx line.

What I am trying to achieve is the following:

I've got a String

**"My new project 2015"**

What I'd like to achieve is that after RegEx'ing it to look like this:

**"Mnp2015"**

So it should extract the first letter from each word of the string, but not the first digit or delete the digit completely.

I've got as far that I get **"Mnp2"**, but cant seem to figure out how to "ignore" the digits.

Using following RegEx at the moment: **"/(?<=\D\s|^)[a-z]/i"**

Comment: does 'test1234' change to 't1234' or 'test1234'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you use above `/(?<=\D\s|^)[a-z]/i` won't work with PCRE regular expressions since the look-behind is not fixed width. At least, that is the error I get when I try it. It is easier in this case simply to assert a word boundary:

```
/\b([a-zA-Z]|\d+)/g
```

This matches the first character of each word starting with a letter while matching any number of digits. [See Regex 101 demo here.](https://regex101.com/r/zV7zN9/1)

If you need to match Unicode letters and numbers, then you can do the following:

```
/\b(\p{L}|\p{N}+)/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the regexp you used to catch numbers should work.

```
(?<=\D\s|^)([a-z]|\d*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:^|(?<=\s))([a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]+\s*
```

Try this.Replace by `$1` or `\1`.See demo

https://regex101.com/r/pM9yO9/4

Answer (score 0):

```
$title = 'My new project 2015 test1234';
$result = preg_replace('/(?:([a-z])[^ ]*(?: |$)| )/i', '$1', $title);
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

This question only provides one sample input string so we have no way of knowing how the project strings might vary.

You don't need to use `preg_match()` or create any temporary arrays of matches; just use `preg_replace()` to remove the characters that you don't want.

`\K` "forgets" the previously matched letter.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/lQUqq))

```
$text = 'My new project 2015';
echo preg_replace('/[a-z]\K[a-z]* /i', '', $text);
// Mnp2015
```